# How Can I Order by two Values using Substring

Tags: php, mysql

I'm Using PHP and MySQL to show some data on the screen, but I need to order rows of a table using 2 columns.

On one column `Restricted`
I have the following json (`["PT","GB"]`)

On the other column `rate` I have decimal values from `0` to `10`

What I'm looking is for a way to order first `Restriced` contains `GB` Then `rate` DESC (If I can use only mysql would be the best)

Current SQL at the moment is

```
SELECT * FROM Partner ORDER BY FIELD (restricted, '%GB%'), FIELD rate DESC
```

I've searched the web for a solution, I've been at this for almost a month, no solution to be found

** EDIT ** 
How it should look

```
Partner Name      |    Countries     |   rate    |

AAAAA             | ["GB","FR","PT"] |    9.0    |
BBBBB             | ["GB","FR","PT"] |    8.8    |
CCCCC             | ["GB","FR","PT"] |    7.2    |

DDDDD             | ["US","FR","PT"] |    9.0    |
EEEEE             | ["US","FR","PT"] |    8.8    |
FFFFF             | ["US","FR","PT"] |    7.2    |
```

Comment: SELECT * FROM Partner WHERE Restricted LIKE '%GB%' ORDER BY restricted, rate DESC ?

Comment: Doesn't work cause I have to show all rows even if it doesn't contain the GB. Anyway thanks for the quick reply, using LIKE it will lock the data shown to only the lines that have GB

Comment: "I have to show all rows even if it doesn't contain the GB" -> Skip the WHERE/LIKE part then? :-) I don't understand.

Comment: Please show an example of your data and how you would like to see it ordered.

Comment: I've added a demo table to it, So it is possible to see the order I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use below mentioned steps:

1. Break your records in 2 Parts (Having 'GB' and not Having 'GB').
2. Sort both record-sets separately as per you logic
3. join both records using UNION ALL

so you query should be as below:

```
(SELECT * FROM partner where restricted like '%GB%' ORDER BY restricted, 
rate DESC)
union all
(SELECT * FROM partner where restricted not like '%GB%' ORDER BY restricted, 
rate DESC)
```

Comment: I think this is a probable solution! Thanks! :D

Comment: Somehow Mysql doesn't order by rate correctly, At the moment what I did was create 2 separately queries and then unite them with PHP. Not the best solution cause it slows down the website loading time.